# Can't connect to PyMongo DB on Kubernetes

Tags: python, kubernetes, pymongo, istio

Everything worked fine when I ran it on Docker, but after I migrated it to Kubernetes it stopped connecting to the DB. It says:

```
pymongo.errors.ServerSelectionTimeoutError
pymongo.errors.ServerSelectionTimeoutError: connection closed
```

whenever I try to access a page that uses the DB.

I connect like this:

```
app.config['MONGO_DBNAME'] = 'pymongo_db'
app.config['MONGO_URI'] = 'mongodb://fakeuser:FakePassword@ds1336984.mlab.com:63984/pymongo_db'
```

Any way to get it to connect?

Edit:

I think it has more so to do with the Istio sidecars as when deployed on Kubernetes minus Istio, it runs normally. The issue only appears when running Istio.

Comment: Is the name of your mongodb service ds1336984.mlab.com? Is it inside Kubernetes?

Comment: @TitoGarrido Yes. It's not inside Kubernetes, no. It doesn't work with Istio. Came across this: https://istio.io/docs/tasks/traffic-management/egress/#calling-external-services-directly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely Istio (the Envoy sidecar) is controlling egress traffic. You can check if you have any `ServiceEntry` and `VirtuaService` in your cluster for your specific application:

```
$ kubectl -n <your-namespace> get serviceentry
$ kubectl -n <your-namespace> get virtualservice
```

If they exist, check if they are allowing traffic to `ds1336984.mlab.com`. If they don't exist you will have to [create](https://istio.io/docs/tasks/traffic-management/egress/) them.

Comment: Yes, I just came across this a few moments ago. Thanks for the answer :)